# How to retrieve the array elements in a tuple in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

when I used `numpy.nonzero()`, e.g. `numpy.nonzero(bool_row)`, where `bool_row` is a `series` containing `boolean` values. It returns a tuple, which contains only one array. I want to retrieve the elements in the array and put them in a list. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When indexing, a tuple is the same as actual values, e.g.

```
x[1,2]
x[(1,2)]
idx = (1,2); x[idx]
```

So in you case, the result of `nonzero` can be used directly as the indexing tuple.

```
In [566]: x=np.arange(10,20)

In [567]: idx = np.nonzero(x%2)

In [568]: idx
Out[568]: (array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], dtype=int32),)

In [569]: x[idx]
Out[569]: array([11, 13, 15, 17, 19])
```

From the `nonzero` docs

> The corresponding non-zero
>       values can be obtained with::

```
    a[nonzero(a)]
```

If you need a list instead of an array, you'll have add the `.tolist()` method.